# How do I make a directory in Linux without it being made in other users on the server?

Tags: server, package-management, directory, users, system-settings

I recently ssh into my company's airflow server, so there are multiple users on this server. Whenever I make a new directory say  it makes the directory in all of the other users as well. How can I set it up where I am only making a directory in one user, not all users on the server?

Additionally it says that I have specific versions of certain packages like Python 2.7.5 but I also have Python 3 installed?

I'm trying to better understand the linux system and having multiples users on a Linux server, so an explanation as to why and what is happening would be great!

Comment: If, as it seems, all the users have the same home directory, you cannot. What's the OS on the "airflow server"? Can you `getent passwd user1`? Is every user using the same `ssh` command? Like `ssh root@airflow`?

Comment: It’s on a Linux OS. Each user has their own id like aho@(ip address of server)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared space, then the directory will be visible to other users.

But you can give users read, write, and executable access exclusively using `chmod`.
Which will essentially not let them read the contents of the files.

I suggest you read this, it will give you an idea of how permissions work in Linux. [Click Me.](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php)